# Remove directory in a remote machine using shell script

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm using Mac machine and I need to connect to remote machine(Linux) and remove the contents of a directory in the remote machine. Tried using

```
ssh root@server-address rm -rf testdir
```

It prompts me for the password in the terminal. Is there any way through which I can delete the contents of directory without having to manually enter the password for the remote machine? I want to do this using shell script. As I'm new to shell, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ssh root@server-address "rm -rf testdir" #suggest you quote the command
```

looks fine.

You can work-around the password prompt by the steps mentioned [[ here ]](https://linuxconfig.org/passwordless-ssh).

Comment: I generated keys using ssh-keygen. However, while copying the public key to remote-host using ssh-copy-id, i get '-bash: ssh-copy-id: command not found error'. Any thought?

Comment: @Harish use scp to copy the key manually `scp /local/machine/path/to/public_key root@server-address:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 1):

To perform SSH login without entering a password you should use ssh-keygen.
See for example [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id).
Then your command is o.k.

Comment: I generated keys using ssh-keygen. However, while copying the public key to remote-host using ssh-copy-id, i get '-bash: ssh-copy-id: command not found error'. Any thought?

Comment: Which OS are you using? It should be installed by default... However, alternatively, you could manually copy the contents of your public key `id_rsa.pub` in the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server, in the '.ssh' folder in the home of the user you use to connect (`/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` in this case).

Comment: ssh-copy-id command ends up in error. However, manually copying the public key did the trick for me. Thanks for the help